# Can not connect to DataStax Enterprise Graph Db C# Driver

Tags: c#, datastax, datastax-enterprise-graph

Why is this not working?

Getting the following error:

Dse.NoHostAvailableException: 'None of the hosts tried for query are available

with the following connection code:

```
IDseCluster dseCluster = DseCluster.Builder()
                .AddContactPoint("ourdomain.com").WithPort(9042)
                .WithAuthProvider(new DsePlainTextAuthProvider("---username--", "---password---"))
                .WithGraphOptions(new GraphOptions().SetName("DSE_GRAPH_QUICKSTART"))
                .Build();

            IDseSession session = dseCluster.Connect();
```

Answer (score 0):

The username and password was incorrect... the error message was misleading.